# readOnly: true does not prevent keyboard on textfield focus on BB10 Webworks

Tags: keyboard, focus, sencha-touch-2, textfield, blackberry-webworks

I am using a textfield as a read-only field by setting `readOnly: true`. When the user taps on the textfield, a listview is pushed from which the user makes a selection, and is then returned back to the previous view with the value of the textfield set to what the user selected.

This works great on iOS and Android as expected and the keyboard does not show. On BlackBerry 10 webworks, it shows the listview and the user can select is returned to the previous view with the correct value, but, as soon as the user taps the textfield the keyboard is also shown which survives the screen transition and is then dismissed.

Is this potentially a bug?

Answer (score 0):

For preventing the keyboard you can listen to "touchstart" event and prevent it with

```
e.preventDefault();
```

on "touchend" event you could call you method which opens the list view.